# Storing CipherValue of ConnectionString

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm having trouble making my connection string a CipherValue. I have read the [microsoft library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) but it kinda hard to follow along. This is what I have so far.

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myDatabase" connectionString="Server={hostname};Initial Catalog={database};User ID={username};Password={password};"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And in my designer I have 4 inputs for hostname, database, username and password and 1 remember me check box and a connect button. I would like to make the connectionString="ACipherValue" to secure the database credentials. What I have so far in my connect button click event is:

```
Dim connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("users").ConnectionString

connString = connString.Replace("{hostname}", txtHostname.Text)
connString = connString.Replace("{database}", txtDatabase.Text)
connString = connString.Replace("{username}", txtUsername.Text)
connString = connString.Replace("{password}", txtPassword.Text)

MsgBox(connString.ToString)
```

The message box show the correct connection string to connect to my database. My problem is I do not know how to update my **app.config** connection string to a CipherValue. Is it possible or I should try another method?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Microsoft recommended method, using the `aspnet_regiis` tool.

[Secure connection strings in web.config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is, is it possible. It is possible as I have done it.

One way to do it is to store your data in the app.config as encrypted CipherValues and then decrypt the CipherValues before use.

Comment: Hi, Can you teach me how it is done? And is it possible to update the CipherVaules in the app.config? Because there is a possibility that we will change the password of the database from time to time. Thank you